# What do negative eigenvalues for Laplacian matrix, if possible, represent?

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, positive-semidefinite, graph-laplacian

I created a Laplacian matrix for data points, which is $L = D - A$, 
and when I do compute the eigenvalues of $L$, I sometimes get a negative eigenvalue. I know that for nonlinear dimensionality reduction (manifold learning), I need to use eigenvectors that correspond to the $M$ smallest eigenvalues, but I thought $L$ is always positive semidefinite...

What do negative eigenvalues of the Laplacian matrix represent?

Comment: A will have large positive values along the diagonal and D will probably have 0 there. You may want to normalize it? Wikipedia mentions two ways, symmetric and random walk normalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix#Symmetric_normalized_Laplacian

Comment: You should double-check how you're constructing $L$ to make sure it's correct. In particular, $L$ should be weakly diagonally dominant.

Comment: It is also relevant to state if the negative eigenvalues are nearly zero (suggesting rounding errors) or very large (indicating a more serious error as suggested by Christopher A. Wong). The actual value of the negative eigenvalue(s), might offer suggestions as to the nature of the bug. A negative integer value suggests a systematic miscount of the nonzero off diagonal values, where the opposite suggest the rows are being treated differently. Have your code compute all eigenvalues for a suitably small matrix and compare with another program.

Comment: I coded it wrong. When I fixed it, I got the answer I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about the [Laplacian matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplacian_matrix) of a [simple (undirected) graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_graph), you were right: it never has negative eigenvalues. As such, negative eigenvalues of the Laplacian do not represent anything; they merely indicate that you made a mistake in computing the Laplacian or finding its eigenvalues. That's all one can say with the information you provided.

If you are somehow working with a directed graph, then it is not clear what the Laplacian even means (what are the diagonal entries?). Even if you overcome this obstacle in the definition, you will typically end up with complex eigenvalues since the matrix is no longer symmetric.

---

I suggest this: if you wrote your own code (or used built-in functions of a computer algebra system) to compute the eigenvalues, then you may post your code on the relevant Q&A Community (such as [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/), [Mathematica Stack Exchange](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) or [ASKSAGE](https://ask.sagemath.org/)). In that case, you may want to read the [hints provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) to avoid your question being closed as off-topic.